# Does WCF's netMsmqBinding requires any MSMQ package installation at the client side?

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I'd like to use WCF+MSMQ(netMsmqBinding) and I was wondering if I'd need to install anything MSMQ related at the client side, other than my client application and the .NET framework of-course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need MSMQ installed on both the service and the consumer sides.

Edit: just to embellish the answer - the reason you need MSMQ installed is that when you send a message to a queue on another machine, what is really happening is that you are sending a message to the queue manager on the senders machine, which is sending a message to the queue manager on the receivers machine, which is sending a message to the queue.

Each "send" is a single logical action and is what gives MSMQ durability.

Comment: MSMQ, like TCP, is a transport protocol. Both ends need to be able to talk the same protocol to communicate.